# How can I transfer a swipe from a UIScrollView to a UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

Maybe a bad title, but I did my best.

Here's what I have: A menu on the left side, which can be opened by panning (from a small vertical bar to almost half my view). The designer thought it a good idea to insert a horizontally scrolling menu right there.

I made all this, but when I scroll horizontally in my menu (so not opening or closing the menu), I can't close the menu by swiping the scrollview more to the left, because it bounces (it also does not work when bouncing is off).

Does anyone have an idea how I can trigger my `UIPanGestureRecognizer` when the `UIScrollView` is scrolled beyond its right edge? Or any other idea how I can solve this?

The reason I made this title is because I have all the code for opening and closing the menu in my `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, and I think it's better if I just trigger the recognizer instead of re-writing some code.

Comment: I found something, but it does not work completely: in `scrollViewDidScroll:` I disabled the user interaction on the `UIScrollView` when the user scrolled beyond the bounds. This has the issue that when the user scrolls fast, the `UIScrollView` bounces a little, and I think that in `scrollViewDidScroll:` there is no reliable way to check if the user is scrolling manually or the scrollview is just bouncing.

Comment: If you're already in `scrollViewDidScroll:` and figured out whether the user is at the "end" of the content (which is when you want to close the menu, correct? You don't want to close before then?), why not call the action of the gesture recognizer immediately from there? Other solutions probably also require careful design and `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` to make both recognizers work, the one of the scroll view and yours (then you gotta distinguish between them somehow in the delegates)

Comment: @Gero yes I could call the close action immediately, but that would not make it interactive. Also, the user may swipe forcefully and trigger it by accident, when all they wanted was to simply go to the right of the scrolling menu view...

Comment: Hm... that's a tough one and tbh I don't think it's the best design your designer made. You're basically trying to distinguish between intentions for very similar interactions here. There might be a way with delayed touches (as the scroll view already supports this) and regocnizing multiple gesture recognizers at once, but I can't come up with a general solution on the top of my head. I'd suggest talking to your designer if that"s still an option? Maybe include a small "border" that you can attach your recognizer to instead of the scroll view (or its underlying view)?